# Magento2 : Random Facts or Funny Facts

Tags: discussion

Magento2 already release its stable release. Can anyone share the Random facts Or Funny facts of Magento2 ? Same like this [link](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/438/the-magento-facts) Or this [link](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/lets-make-this-fun-ish).

*Now its time to Magento2* :)

Comment: The answers in this should probably form a community wiki post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/requirejs/text.js`

Line 311 - `//Why Java, why is this so awkward?`

Line 369 - `//XPCOM, you so crazy`

Line 56  - `//Would love to dump the ActiveX crap in here. Need IE 6 to die first.`

Line 353 - `//Avert your gaze!`

Comment: This is not really M2 code. It's require js code, not written by the M2 core team.

Answer (score 10):

This one takes the cake in my opinion: [`Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Breadcrumbs::_beforeToHtml()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Widget/Breadcrumbs.php#L55)

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    // TODO - Moved to Beta 2, no breadcrumbs displaying in Beta 1
    // $this->assign('links', $this->_links);
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```

What's so funny about it is that the same thing [exists in M1](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Breadcrumbs.php#L64). So this is not about the beta 2 of M2. It's about beta2 of M1.

The other things below are just bonus:

In [`lib/web/css/docs/index.html`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/web/css/docs/index.html#L334)

```
background-color: @nav__background-color; // ToDo UI: todo inline comment
```

In [`Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Action/Attribute/Save.php`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Action/Attribute/Save.php#L152)

```
 // TODO why use ObjectManager?
```

I wonder the same. Why?

Comment: It means that they are doing only code conversion for M2 for specific module :)

Answer (score 8):

src/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/zxcvbn.js

line 343

```
fuckyou, fuckme, fucker, fuckoff, fucking, fuckit, fuckyou2, fucked, fuckyou1, fuck_inside, fuckface, assfuck, fuckers, fuckthis
```

Seriously how many of us keep such passwords :)

Answer (score 7):

In `src/vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/prototype/window.js` there is a comment which says `// Fucking IE select issue` on line `1314`.

Comment: this is not really from Magento. It's prototype.

Answer (score 6):

`src/vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/prototype/window.js` on line `1770`

```
// Why?? Ask IE
```

and on line `860`
    `// Check for this stupid IE that sends dumb events`

Answer (score 5):

`setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/FileScanner.php` has 29 `goto`-statements. And that's not the only place in Magento that has `goto`-statements.

Answer (score 3):

I quite like `href="#TODO"` in `magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/js/navigation-menu.js`. They're trying to send the user 'todo' it.

Answer (score 1):

`/vendor/magento/module-backup/Model/ResourceModel/Helper.php` line 112

```
//TODO fix me
$sql = 'SHOW CREATE TABLE ' . $quotedTableName;
$data = $this->getConnection()->fetchRow($sql);
$script .= isset($data['Create Table']) ? $data['Create Table'] . ";\n" : '';
```

or this

`/vendor/magento/module-configurable-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Type/Configurable.php` line 651

```
// @todo understand why do we need this condition
if ($this->_getSuperAttributeId($linkId, $attrParams['id'])) {
    $productSuperAttrId = $this->_getSuperAttributeId($linkId, $attrParams['id']);
} elseif (isset($this->_superAttributesData['attributes'][$linkId][$attrParams['id']])) {
    $attributes = $this->_superAttributesData['attributes'];
    $productSuperAttrId = $attributes[$linkId][$attrParams['id']]['product_super_attribute_id'];
    $this->_collectSuperDataLabels($data, $productSuperAttrId, $linkId, $variationLabels);
} else {
    $productSuperAttrId = $this->_getNextAttrId();
    $this->_collectSuperDataLabels($data, $productSuperAttrId, $linkId, $variationLabels);
}
```

It was a little shock after hours of investigation...